Snowflake: how to convert wall clock time to UTC at fall daylight savings?
I have hourly data recorded in wall clock time in Chicago where 1am appears twice on the day when fall daylight savings occurs (which is expected - during fall daylight savings, a wall clock should experience the hour from 1am to 2am twice, but these correspond to different UTC times).
I would like to convert these wall clock times to UTC, ideally using some graceful built-in Snowflake conversion.
However, the convert_timezone() function appears not to differentiate between the two 1am wall clock times.
with data as (
select to_timestamp_ntz('2023-11-05 00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') as ts_local
union all
select to_timestamp_ntz('2023-11-05 01:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') as ts_local
union all 
select to_timestamp_ntz('2023-11-05 01:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') as ts_local
union all 
select to_timestamp_ntz('2023-11-05 02:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') as ts_local
)

select
    ts_local,
    convert_timezone('America/Chicago', 'UTC', ts_local)
from data

query result



TS_LOCAL
CONVERT_TIMEZONE()




2023-11-05 00:00:00.000
2023-11-05 05:00:00.000


2023-11-05 01:00:00.000
2023-11-05 06:00:00.000


2023-11-05 01:00:00.000
2023-11-05 06:00:00.000


2023-11-05 02:00:00.000
2023-11-05 08:00:00.000



I would like row 3 to be 2023-11-05 07:00:00.000 after applying convert_timezone(). Is there a different Snowflake function that does this?

The convertion needs to happen at the source at the time of the event, because the source knows it's 1am first time verse 1am second time, where-as two date values of 1am do not have the details. Unless those have timezone information, like 1am +7 and 1 am +8 to let you know which timesystem/offset is applied.

Yes, I would like to also pass some timezone information like "CST" and "CDT", but 'convert_timezone()' won't accept those as timezones, hence my use of 'America/Chicago', which is ambiguous for this one hour each year.

How do you know that row #3 should be that value?  What logical rule are you applying to 2 identical records which you are expecting to have different outputs?  How was your original wall clock data stored on Snowflake?  NTZ?

@MikeWalton I agree that there needs to be some other identifying information to disambiguate - my question is, what should that be? 2023-11-05 01:00 in America/Chicago timezone does not correspond to a unique UTC timestamp, and Snowflake's convert_timezone() doesn't know how to convert from "CST" and "CDT" to "UTC".

I think my confusion stems from the fact that converting back and forth using convert_timezone('America/Chicago', 'UTC', convert_timezone('UTC', 'America/Chicago', '2023-11-05 07:00:00.000'::timestamp_ntz)) returns 2023-11-05 06:00:00.000 rather than 2023-11-05 07:00:00.000. Is there a different value I can use besides America/Chicago that will result in convert_timezone() being an invertible function?

Had the data been captured in a LTZ timestamp, rather than a string or NTZ timestamp, then the conversions would be more accurate, because LTZ is stored as UTC in Snowflake.  However, since you're starting with something that doesn't contain any offset information, Snowflake has no way to discern what is different about the data.  I'm not sure I'm understanding your confusion, tbh.  What you really need on this data is offset information as part of the wall-clock time that you are starting with.  Without that, not even a human can look at that data and make a determination.
